# PlayFramework 1.2.7 application deploy to CloudBees

Tags: playframework-1.x, cloudbees, playframework-evolutions

I'll try found question, but I couldn't.

I'll try to deploy my application to CloudBees platform.
In my application.conf file I set params:

```
###############################################################
# Production config ###########################################
###############################################################
%production.application.mode=prod
%production.jpa.ddl=create
%production.db.url="jdbc:mysql:"${MYSQL_URL_EASYBOOKDB}
%production.db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
%production.db.user=${MYSQL_USERNAME_EASYBOOKDB}
%production.db.pass=${MYSQL_PASSWORD_EASYBOOKDB}
```

before that, i linked my app with db

```
bees app:bind -db easybook -a zolt/easybook -as easybookdb
```

I have installed cloudbees module for playframework.
I deploy my app, like that:

```
play bees:app:deploy --%production
```

have that answer:

```
upload complete, response=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApplicationDeployArchiveResponse>
<id>zolt/easybook</id>
<url>http://easybook.zolt.cloudbees.net</url>
</ApplicationDeployArchiveResponse>
Application zolt/easybook deployed: http://easybook.zolt.cloudbees.net
```

after that, i go to link http://easybook.zolt.cloudbees.net and see tomcat error page...

in log i see that stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class                play.server.ServletWrapper 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:  play.exceptions.DatabaseException: Cannot connected to the database, Communications link failure 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at play.db.DBPlugin.onApplicationStart(DBPlugin.java:161) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at play.plugins.PluginCollection.onApplicationStart(PluginCollection.java:525) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at play.Play.start(Play.java:533) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at play.Play.init(Play.java:305) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at    play.server.ServletWrapper.contextInitialized(ServletWrapper.java:78) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:825) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at com.staxnet.appserver.TomcatServerBase.startContainer(TomcatServerBase.java:120) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at com.staxnet.appserver.TomcatServerBase.start(TomcatServerBase.java:190) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at com.staxnet.appserver.StaxAppServer.main(StaxAppServer.java:89) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at com.staxnet.appserver.SnazAppServer.main(SnazAppServer.java:26) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at net.stax.appserver.bootstrap.Bootstrap.invokeAppServerMain(Bootstrap.java:41) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at net.stax.appserver.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:30) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:  Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:348) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2391) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2428) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2213) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:797) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:389) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at play.db.DBPlugin.onApplicationStart(DBPlugin.java:109) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    ... 17 more 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:  Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:257) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:298) 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:    ... 28 more 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:  Jan 07, 2014 10:56:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start 
Jan 07 02:56:58 easybook i-9cd9d7e1:  SEVERE: Error listenerStart
```

if i try connect to DB over MysqWorkbench it's all fine... 
what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not binding your database with your application in the right way.

According with [Play1 ClickStart](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/play1-clickstart) in which the database binding is working. These are the steps:

1.In [application.conf](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/play1-clickstart/blob/master/src/conf/application.conf) you should have this:

```
db=java:comp/env/jdbc/mydb
jpa.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

2.Bind the application to the database

```
$bees app:bind -a appName -db dbName -as mydb
```

3.Redeploy the application

```
 bees app:deploy -a MY_APP -t tomcat7 myapp.war
```

Official documentation about Play1 is [here](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Play1DeployPlugin).

Comment: this config for playframework 2.x, but i'm used playframework 1.2.7. I'll try to clearly specify the parameters, but it's not worked.

Comment: Sorry, I just updated it for Play 1. Could you try it again, please?

Comment: Thanks, @felix, but it not work too. After that changes i have error: `A database error occured : Cannot connected to the database, Name mydb is not bound in this Context`

Comment: You were deploying on Tomcat 6, please deploy on Tomcat 7. I have just updated the third point: bees app:deploy -a MY_APP -t tomcat7 myapp.war

Comment: Just checked Cannot connected to the database : Name jdbc is not bound in this Context message happens because you didn't bind the app with the app. $bees app:bind -a appName -db dbName -as mydb. On Tomcat 7 I could check if you did it properly. Be sure to do the binding before deploying the application.

Comment: Check the binding with: bees app:bindings -a zolt/easybook

Comment: Checking for SDK updates...
    Applications bindings:
    papertrail-zolt/easybook papertrail:zolt/easybook
    mydb cb-db:zolt/easybook

Comment: The binding seems to be good. So, if you did the binding and after that you deployed your app should work. Note that if you deploy and after that you do the binding then it will not work. Please, open a support ticket so we could take a look in deep to it.